# How to split letters with bracket and numbers in R?

Tags: r, strsplit

The string is s = '[12]B1[16]M5'

I want to split it as the following results with **strsplit** function in R:

`let <- c('[12]B', '[16]M')`

`num <- c(1, 5)`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expression for your task.

```
s = '[12]B1[16]M22'

grx <- gregexpr("\\[.+?\\].+[[:digit:]]?",  s)
let <- do.call(c, regmatches(s, grx))

#let
#[1] "[12]B" "[16]M"
```

If you want to get all chunks (let + num), you can tweak the patter as below. This facilitates extracting the numeric part.

```
grx <- gregexpr("\\[.+?\\].+([[:digit:]]+)",  s)
out <- do.call(c, regmatches(s, grx))

num <- gsub(".+\\][[:alpha:]]+", "", out)

num
[1] "1"  "22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
x <- '[12]B1[16]M2'

let <- unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\[[0-9]{2}\\][A-Z]"))

x <- gsub(pattern = "\\[[0-9]{2}\\][A-Z]",
          replacement = "",
          x)

num <- unlist(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]"))
```

the regular expression `"\\[[0-9]{2}\\][A-Z]"` can be broken down as

- `\\[` an opening bracket
- `[0-9]{2}` a sequence of two consecutive digits
- `\\]` a closing bracket
- `[A-Z]` a sequence of exactly one upper case letter

Answer (score 1):

**1) strapply** Create a regular expression, `pat` which matches the two parts and then extract each separately using `strapply`.  The first capture group (first parenthesized portion of regular expression) consists of a left square bracket `"\\["` the smallest string `".*?"` until the right square bracket `"\\]"` followed by any character `"."` .  The second capture group consists of one or more digits `"\\d+"`.

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(\\[.*?\\].)(\\d+)"

let <- strapply(s, pat, simplify = c)   
num <- strapply(s, pat, ~ as.numeric(..2), simplify = c)

let
## [1] "[12]B" "[16]M"

num
## [1] 1 5
```

**1a) Variation**

This could also be expressed as this `mapply` producing a 2 component list:

```
mapply(strapply, s, pat, c(~ ..1, ~ as.numeric(..2)), simplify = "c", 
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "[12]B" "[16]M"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 5
```

**2) gsub/read.table**  This uses no packages -- only `gsub` and `read.table`.  `pat` is defined in (1).  It returns a data frame with the results in two coiumns:

```
read.table(text = gsub(pat, "\\1 \\2\n", s), as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("let", "num"))
##     let num
## 1 [12]B   1
## 2 [16]M   5
```

**3) gsub/strsplit** This is somewhat similar to (2) but uses `strsplit` rather than `read.table`.  `pat` is from (1).

```
spl <- matrix(strsplit(gsub(pat, "\\1 \\2 ", s), " ")[[1]], 2)
let <- spl[1, ]
num <- as.numeric(spl[2, ])
```